# how to create identity matrix without eye and loop

Tags: matlab

I just wonder whether it's possible to create an identity matrix without eye function, loop, and any matlab build in function. At first I was thinking to use something like this:

```
A = bsxfun(@power, 1:n, (1:n).');
```

Unfortunately, I do not think I can assign value '1' and '0' without using any loop. and this still use build function. any idea?

Comment: Doesn't `bsxfun` count as a Matlab builtin function?

Comment: I don't understand the point of this other than it being a learning exercise. If `bsxfun` is acceptable, how about `diag(ones(1,n))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the neat trick that `A(1:n+1:end)` references the elements of `A` that should be 1, you can simply do:

```
A=zeros(n^2,1);
A(1:n+1:end)=1;
```

And MrAzzaman's suggestion to avoid using `zeros` by intialising `A` by doing `A(n,n)=0;`.

Comment: You don't need to do the `A` and `B` separation - just do `A = zeros(n); A(1:n+1:end)=1;`

Comment: I think zeros can be consider as build in function right?

Comment: @David you can avoid the "built-in" function `zeros` by using the following: `clear A; A(n,n)=0; A(1:n+1:end)=1;`

Comment: @MrAzzaman Nice one. You should probably post this as your own answer at this stage!

Comment: @David Eh, it would largely just be repeating your answer, with minor tweaks. It's not really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If `bsxfun` is allowed then

```
I = bsxfun( @eq, 1:n, (1:n).' );
```

Answer (score 1):

where **num** is the size of the nxn matrix.

```
function matrix = identity_matrix(num)
matrix = zeros(num);   //this creates a new n by n zero matrix
matrix(1:num+1:end)=1;
```

Comment: Virtually the same as David's answer.  Don't see how this adds anything new.